# I created a basic CRUD GUI with Hibernate, but I get "index out of bound exception". What could be the problem?

Tags: java, hibernate, search, orm, crud

Here is the GUI of my application with index out of bound error message:
[image: GUI wit out of bound exception]

Here is the code for the search algorith:

```
  private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        try {
            String name = this.searchTextField.getText();
            if (name.equals("")) {
                FillData();
            }else{
            session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Items.class);
            Items list = (Items) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name).ignoreCase()).uniqueResult();
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
            if (list.equals(null)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No results");
                }else{

                if (dtm.getColumnCount()==0) {
                dtm.addColumn("Name");
                dtm.addColumn("Category");
                dtm.addColumn("Quantity");
                dtm.addColumn("Net Price (per unit)");
                dtm.addColumn("Gross Pice (per unit)");
                dtm.addColumn("Net Price (total)");
                dtm.addColumn("Gross Price (total)");
                }
                Font f = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16);      
                JTableHeader header = itemTable.getTableHeader();
                header.setFont(f);
                itemTable.setRowHeight(25);

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{list.getName(), list.getCategory().getName(), getQuantity().get(i).getQuantity(), list.getNetPrice(), list.getNetPrice()*(list.getVatRate()+1), getQuantity().get(i).getQuantity()*list.getNetPrice(), list.getNetPrice()*(list.getVatRate()+1)*getQuantity().get(i).getQuantity()});
                }

                this.itemTable.setModel(dtm);}}} catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage()); 
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I also tried with a different algorithm where **Items list** was actually **List list** but I realized I only going to have single results.

**Any ideas for a solution is well appreciated!**

I am *trying* to write out the necessary data with this class. Note the word trying.

```
     public List<ItemAndQuantity> getQuantity()
        {
        List<ItemAndQuantity> quantity = new ArrayList<ItemAndQuantity>();       
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
//  Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(t.Flow * a.In_Or_Out), i.Item_ID from TRANSACTIONS t, and i.Item_ID = t.Item_ID group by i.Item_ID");
                Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join a.transactions t join t.item i group by i.itemId");
                //Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join Transactions t join Items i group by i.itemId");
                quantity.addAll(query.list());
                transaction.commit();
            } 
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        finally {
             session.close();}
             return quantity;
        }
```

Here is the exception I have:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length
>   0 Hibernate: select items0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID1_2_, items0_.NAME as
>   NAME2_2_, items0_.NET_PRICE as NET_PRIC3_2_, items0_.VAT_RATE as
>   VAT_RATE4_2_, items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_ from APP.ITEMS
>   items0_ Hibernate: select categories0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY1_1_0_,
>   categories0_.NAME as NAME2_1_0_ from APP.CATEGORIES categories0_ where
>   categories0_.CATEGORY_ID=? Hibernate: select items0_.CATEGORY_ID as
>   CATEGORY5_2_0_, items0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID1_2_0_, items0_.ITEM_ID as
>   ITEM_ID1_2_1_, items0_.NAME as NAME2_2_1_, items0_.NET_PRICE as
>   NET_PRIC3_2_1_, items0_.VAT_RATE as VAT_RATE4_2_1_,
>   items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_1_ from APP.ITEMS items0_ where
>   items0_.CATEGORY_ID=? Hibernate: select items0_.ITEM_ID as
>   ITEM_ID1_2_, items0_.NAME as NAME2_2_, items0_.NET_PRICE as
>   NET_PRIC3_2_, items0_.VAT_RATE as VAT_RATE4_2_, items0_.CATEGORY_ID as
>   CATEGORY5_2_ from APP.ITEMS items0_ Hibernate: select
>   categories0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY1_1_0_, categories0_.NAME as
>   NAME2_1_0_ from APP.CATEGORIES categories0_ where
>   categories0_.CATEGORY_ID=?    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
>     at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)     at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)     at
>   stock.view.StockView.searchButtonActionPerformed(StockView.java:479)
>     at
>   stock.view.StockView$FormListener.actionPerformed(StockView.java:359)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) Hibernate:
>   select items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_0_, items0_.ITEM_ID as
>   ITEM_ID1_2_0_, items0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID1_2_1_, items0_.NAME as
>   NAME2_2_1_, items0_.NET_PRICE as NET_PRIC3_2_1_, items0_.VAT_RATE as
>   VAT_RATE4_2_1_, items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_1_ from APP.ITEMS
>   items0_ where items0_.CATEGORY_ID=?   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Why do you have a for loop that's only for one iteration?

Comment: Sorry, that was for the earlier version when I used **List<Items> list**

Comment: Hi, please follow the @Nathan Hughes answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is generated when your code is trying to get the first element out of an empty list.

Instead of testing for null: `list.equals(null)`, check for empty: `list.isEmpty()`.

null and empty are two different concepts. A null list is a reference that doesn't point to anything. An empty list is a reference to an existing object implementing List that contains 0 elements.

Furthermore, `list.equals(null)` will never work, if list is null then the code will cause a NullPointerException. Instance methods (like equals) need an object to be executed on, you can't execute an instance method on a null reference. So if you want to check for null you would have to use `list == null` instead.

That's why you will see code that checks for a non-null, non-empty list like this:

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
```

because it checks for both nullness and emptiness. This is safe (avoiding dereferencing null) because it checks for not-null first, and the && operation shortcircuits when list is null.

It is safe to assume you don't have to check that the list returned by Hibernate is null. If the list returned was null then your code would have failed with a NPE.